# I removed __init__.py by mistake

Tags: python, django, migration

I have deleted `__init__.py` by mistake along with the migrations folder in my django project

What should i do now?

Answer (score 4):

This is where version control comes handy. But it looks like you do not have version control.

Here is what migrations do - They help you evolve the database over time. Typically, it is useful to keep versions, etc which can help you revert application to a previous stable version, etc..
Now, by losing the migrations folder, all you lost is that versioning history. 
This does not mean the application would stop working. You could create the `__init__.py` file and create an [initial migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations).

> The “initial migrations” for an app are the migrations that create the
>   first version of that app’s tables. Usually an app will have just one
>   initial migration, but in some cases of complex model
>   interdependencies it may have two or more.